# Sed command with \n

Tags: macos, bash, unix, ubuntu

I have a database of partially-corrupt JSON files. The person who wrote them for some reason included an extra comma at the end of the file. There are zillions of these files so I need to fix them. This is what it looks like:

```
{
"foo": "bar",
"foo1": "bar1",
"foo2": "bar2",
}
```

So I'm trying to use the sed command to get rid of the commas. Right now, I have sed 's|',\n}'|'\n}'|' but it's not modifying the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please format your code, so it is more readable.  For instance, put backticks around the "sed..." line instead of quotes (or in this case, an opening quote)

Comment: Do you have Perl installed? It's WAY easier with Perl than sed

Answer (score 0):

The version of `sed` that ships with OS X doesn't treat `\n` as a newline character, but as an escaped 'n' (which reduces to a regular 'n'). Since you are using `bash`, you can try the following:

```
sed $'s|,}|\\\n|' file.txt
```

The `$'...'` is a special type of quoting in `bash` that allows for certain escapes to be treated specially. `\\\n` is an escaped backslash followed by a newline, which `bash` presents to `sed` as a single escaped newline character.

UPDATE: After remembering to use `$` instead of a newline character in the search text, I realized that you can't match a command followed by a brace on the following line (or at least, I don't know how with my limited command of `sed`).

Comment: After searching around, I found this: sed 'N;s|,\n}|}|' but now it deletes the curly brace instead of the comma.

Comment: Running sed $'s|,\\\n}|\\\n}|' file.txt returns sed: 1: "s|,\
}|\
}|": unterminated substitute pattern

Comment: This gives: ` unterminated substitute pattern` on OSX 10.6.2

Answer (score 0):

You could try awk:

```
awk '{ if (/}/) sub(",$", "", last); if (last) print last; last=$0 } END { print last }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one sed solution that works on OSX as well:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N; $!ba' -e 's/,\(\n}\)/\1/' file.json
```

As alternative you can install gnu-sed on OSX using:

```
sudo brew install gnu-sed
```

and then run:

```
gsed -e ':a; N; $!ba; s/,\(\n}\)/\1/' file.json
```